# My Regex to find IPs works but how to exclude certain IPs

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

See example at [Rubular.com](https://rubular.com/r/LJI8F6N9DjilT9)

It works to find IP from error.log

```
((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).+(not found or unable to stat)
```

but I need to ignore/exclude some IPs something like

```
((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).+(not found or unable to stat)(?!563.77.198.102)
```

but it does not work. Thx for a hint where I make a mistake.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(\b(?!563\.77\.198\.102)(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).+(not found or unable to stat)`  https://rubular.com/r/goWUFuxXuZ9BDo

Comment: Yes! ...but I need to ignore second IP

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? What do you mean by exclude some IPs? Can there be more?

Comment: Your example exactly has ignored predifined IP (\b(?!563\.77\.198\.102) ! but now it catches second variable IP from log - 144.76.224.241 - this second variable IP also should be ignored.

Comment: Although thx a lot - you exactly answered my question...as to second IP I know how to solve outside regex within firewall config. I'd be glad if you post your solution as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative lookahead at the end will always be true as there is no ip number after `not found or unable to stat`. But that does not give the desired check.

You could move the negative lookahead before matching the ip like pattern and place a wordboundary `\b` in front of the negative lookahead to set the boundary.

You could also add a word boundary after the last 3 digits `[0-9]{1,3}\b` as the pattern continues with `.+` which will match any character 1+ times and can also match a digit.

Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
\b((?!563\.77\.198\.102)(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\b.+(not found or unable to stat)
```

About the pattern

- `\b(` Word boundary, capture **group 1**

  - `(?!563\.77\.198\.102)` Negative lookahead, if what is directly on the right is not this ip
  - `(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` Match an ip like numer
- `)\b` Close group 1 and word boundary
- `.+` Match any char except a newline 1+ times
- `(not found or unable to stat)` Capture the text in **group 2**

[Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/X7xkSzdsCxqfCG)

Answer (score 1):

Use [the best regex trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) which is about discarding matches to capture only what you want. You do that by using alternation `|` and putting anything you want to *discard* on the left and anything you want to *match* as a capture group on the right end:

```
/discard this|(capture)/
/discard this|and this|(capture)/
```

So, if you want to omit some IPs, put them on the left and capture what you want on the right:

```
563\.77\.198\.102|((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).+(not found or unable to stat)
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZviTio/3)

[Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/8EeiLlV8frLmjS)

If you examine the captured content you will see that for each line but the excluded IP the capture groups are populated.